# How to overwrite magento controller action from own module?

Tags: magento, controller, extends, overwrite, magento-1.8

I try to overwrite the function `indexAction` from "*app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\controllers\ManageController.php*" with my own.

I duplicated the controller to *app\code\local\Fekete\Newsletter2Go\controllers\ManageController.php* and only let the function `indexAction` there.

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Newsletter/controllers/ManageController.php';

class Fekete_Newsletter2Go_ManageController extends Mage_Newsletter_ManageController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        exit("test");
    }
}
```

Then I added the following code inside the `<config></config>` tags in: *app\code\local\Fekete\Newsletter2Go\etc\config.xml*:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <newsletter>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Fekete_Newsletter2Go before="Mage_Newsletter">
                        Fekete_Newsletter2Go
                    </Fekete_Newsletter2Go>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </newsletter>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

But If I go to **http://example.com/newsletter/manage/** then nothing has changed, my overwrite was not used.

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the cause for the problem. I had to change this:

```
<Fekete_Newsletter2Go before="Mage_Newsletter">
    Fekete_Newsletter2Go
</Fekete_Newsletter2Go>
```

to this:

```
<Fekete_Newsletter2Go before="Mage_Newsletter">Fekete_Newsletter2Go</Fekete_Newsletter2Go>
```